# Provide a more complete dump for failed sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase

Given that all data on such sites will no longer be public, they generally have less of it and it would only need to be done once for each site, I think they should have more complete dump including for example:

- Markdown source
- Revisions
- Anonymised deleted posts?

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our goal is to migrate as many of the questions as we can -- which was certainly true of [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), the majority of whose questions were migrated to:

- Gaming
- Android
- Apple
- Unix/Linux

The remaining list of un-migrateable questions is all that was dumped.